# Save PDF file locally and be able to view it outside of the application

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

Which are my alternatives for downloading a PDF file from the internet and view it later outside of the application?

For now I am downloading it and displaying it in a UIWebView, but I want to be able to download it elsewhere.

```
NSURL *yourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.currentInventoryOfFixtures.pdf.url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:yourURL];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        documentsURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.pdf"];

[data writeToURL:documentsURL atomically:YES];
```

I am thinking to use a UIActivityController and give user the possibility to sent it on his email address.

Comment: What is the issue in using UIActivitycontroller

Comment: I have a download button in the application which has the purpose of doing the entire job.

Comment: What do you mean "download it elsewhere"? The iOS file system is sandboxed.

Comment: Ok, I understand this. So the only valid option is to use the UIActivityController I guess

Comment: Yes you should use UIACTIVITYCONTROLLER.  To provide user access

Comment: Ok, thank you for making it clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

After downloaded the PDF file, and having the path of this file, you could use UIActivityViewController this way:

```
let fileSaved = downloadedFilePath() //Already Downloaded File Path

if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: fileSaved) {
    let dataToShare = [data]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: dataToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(string: String?, result: Bool, items: [AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        print("Completed")
    }

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
            UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
            UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
            UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
            UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
            UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
            UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
            UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
            UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard
        ]
    }
    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```